# Nginx reverse proxy prevent changing host for other locations

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I’m trying to get this done for a couple of days and I can’t. I’m having two web apps, one production and one testing, let’s say `https://production.app` and `https://testing.app`. I need to make a reverse proxy under `https://production.app/location` that points to `https://testing.app/location` (at the moment I only need one functionality from the testing env in prod). The configuration I created indeed proxies this exact location, but that functionality also loads resources from `/static` directory resulting in request to `https://production.app/static/xyz.js` instead of `https://testing.app/static/xyz.js`, and `/static` can’t be proxied. Is there a way to change headers only in this proxied traffic so that it’s `https://testing.app/static` (and of course any other locations)?

Below is my current config (only directives regarding proxy):

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name production.app;
    root /var/www/production.app;

    location /location/ {
        proxy_pass  https://testing.app/location/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Have a good day :)

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want all the `/static/...` requests made from the `production.app/location/` page to be proxied via `http://testing.app` rather than served locally? I can see a possible trick to do it, but I don't understand what do you mean by _any other locations_, give an example of that "other location", please.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thank you for your answer. I mean that if it’s not /static/… but let’s say /img/… it also should be proxied. If there’s no way of doing that please share the trick to handle that single location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question title isn't well written. It has nothing to do about "changing headers", and nginx location, while being essentially tied to the request processing, isn't the right term there too. It should be something like "how to serve the assets requested by proxied page in a different way than the others".

Ok, here we go. First of all, do you really understand what exactly does the following config?

```
location /location/ {
    proxy_pass https://testing.app/location/;
}
```

The URI prefix `/location/` specified after the `https://testing.app` upstream name has the following effect:

1. The `/location/` prefix specified in the `location` directive truncated from the processed URI.
2. Processed UIR is being prepended with the `/location/` prefix specified in the `proxy_pass` directive before being passed to the upstream.

That is, if these prefixes are equal, the following configuration will do the same eliminating those steps (therefore processing the request slightly more efficiently):

```
location /location/ {
    proxy_pass https://testing.app;
}
```

Understanding this is a key concept to the trick we're going to use.

Since all the requests for static assets made from the `/location/` page will have the HTTP [`Referer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) header equal to `http://production.app/location/` (well, unless you specify `no-referer` as you page [referrer policy](https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/#referrer-policy-no-referrer), and if you are, the whole trick won't work at all unless you change it), we can rewrite a request URI that matched some conditions (say start with the `/static/` or `/img/` prefix) redirecting it to some special internal location using the following `if` block (should be placed at the `server` configuration level):

```
if ($http_referer = https://production.app/location/) {
    rewrite ^/static/ /internal$uri;
    rewrite ^/img/ /internal$uri;
    ...
}
```

We can use any prefix, the `/internal` one used here is only as example, however used prefix should not interfere with your existing routes. Next, we will define that special location using the [`internal`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal) keyword:

```
location /internal/ {
    internal;
    proxy_pass https://testing.app/;
}
```

Trailing slash after the `http://testing.app` upstream name here is the essential part. It will make the proxied URI returning to its original state, removing the `/internal/` prefix added by the `rewrite` directive earlier and replacing it with a single slash.

You can use this trick for more than one page using regex pattern to match the `Referer` header value, e.g.

```
if ($http_referer ~ ^https?://production\.app/(page1|page2|page3)/) {
    ...
}
```

You should no try this for anything else but the static assets or it can break the app routing mechanism. This is also only a workaround that should be used for testing purposes only, not something that I can recommend for the production use on a long term basis.

---

BTW, are you sure you really need that

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

line in your location? Do you really understand what does it mean or you are using it just copy-pasting from some other configuration? Check [this](https://serverfault.com/a/1100774/498657) answer to not be surprised if something goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you, it works as expected. As for the title, you're right, I just thought it's about this Host header, that's also why I added proxy_set_header Host :)